# Python Lambda Apply Function Multiple Conditions using OR

Tags: pandas, lambda, apply

I've searched this one and cannot find a solution. I have a multiple data condition where when either condition is met, is summed. In my dataset, I have used "apply" and the lambda function for a single condition <, >. However, I have a continuous data column where a count is based on either a  low value OR a high value. I have tried variations of this below but keep getting a "ValueError:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Let's say my data looks like this: dfdata

```
Site   data  month  day   year
A      4     1      1     2021
A      17    1      2     2021
A      8     1      3     2021
A      7     1      1     2022
A      0     1      2     2022
A      2     1      3     2022
B      3     1      1     2021
B      16    1      2     2021
B      9     1      3     2021
B      2     1      1     2022
B      18    1      2     2022
B      5     1      3     2022
```

I've used a for loop that should give the following result below for evaluating the "data" column and counting the instances of the value < 4 OR > 15. I think that the "|" operator might do this but I get a True/False...

```
sites = ['A','B']
n = len(sites)
dft = pd.DataFrame(); 
for n in sites: 
    dft.loc[:,n] = dfdata[dfdata['Site']==n].groupby(["month", "day"])["data"].apply(lambda x: (x < 4) or (x > 15).sum())
```

the result.

```
month   day   A    B
1       1     0    2
1       2     2    2
1       3     1    0
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use (and should avoid) loops in pandas. Aside from being slow, it also make you intention harder to read.

Here's on solution using pandas functions:

```py
dft = (
    dfdata.query("data < 4 or data > 15")
    .groupby(["month", "day", "Site"])["data"]
    .sum()
    .unstack(fill_value=0)
)
```

The `query` filters for rows whose `data` is <4 or >17. The rest is just adding them up and reshaping the resulting dataframe.

Comment: You might want to use a `pivot_table` with `aggfunc='sum'` here ;)